# Nav2: Message Filter dropping message: frame

Tags: nav2

I'm trying to use the `nav2` package, but I get the following warning when I try to run `bringup_launch.py`

```
[local_costmap.local_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'robot/lidar link/scan' at time 20.296 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
```

My parameters file looks like this:

```yaml
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    set_initial_pose: false
    initial_pose: "{0.0 0.0 0.0 -1.57}"
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml: /app/nemo/config/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    odom_topic: /odom
    enable_groot_monitoring: true
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    controller_frequency: 5.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugin: "goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.10
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.10
      stateful: true
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: true
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.10
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: true
      stateful: true
      critics:
        [
          "RotateToGoal",
          "Oscillation",
          "BaseObstacle",
          "GoalAlign",
          "PathAlign",
          "PathDist",
          "GoalDist",
        ]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: true
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 1.0
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: true
        publish_voxel_map: true
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: true
          marking: true
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: true
      always_send_full_costmap: true
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: true
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: true

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: true
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      robot_radius: 1.0
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: true
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: true
          marking: true
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: true
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: true
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: true
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: true

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    yaml_filename: "nemo/maps/factory.yaml"
    topic_name: "map"
    frame_id: "map"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    save_map_timeout: 5000
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: False

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    expected_planner_frequency: 5.0
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "back_up", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    back_up:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
```

An the `tf` tree:

[image: tf tree]

What can be causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> 20.296

> 1704816550.625...

Something is running at walltime and others on simulation time. So, the items using walltime can't transform because its being provided times in simulation time (20.296) which is *well before* 170...

You should look over your nodes and make sure everything is using or not using sim time as appropriate for your application. From that log message, I'd look at your sensor drivers first.